# Unresolved Dependency error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I keep getting the following error in eclipse for a simple Repository interface.

```
The type org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryByExampleExecutor
cannot be resolved.
It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Its a Play Framework 2.5.1 project with MongoDB. Here're the dependencies in build.sbt.

`libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    javaCore,
    javaJpa,
    "javax.inject" % "javax.inject" % "1",
    "org.springframework" % "spring-core" % "4.3.3.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework" % "spring-context" % "4.3.3.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework" % "spring-beans" % "4.3.4.RELEASE"
    "org.springframework" % "spring-jdbc" % "4.3.4.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-jpa" % "1.10.1.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-commons-core" % "1.4.1.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework" % "spring-expression" % "4.3.3.RELEASE",
    "org.mongodb" % "mongo-java-driver" % "3.2.2",
    "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-mongodb" % "1.9.2.RELEASE",
    "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.9.5" % "test"
)`

[image: This is my UserRepository interface]
[image: UserRepository interface error]

Could someone help me solve this issue

Comment: Is this the right image for the error message?

Comment: @nitind, yes. I've added a new image with the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the spring data commons dependency referenced by spring-data-jpa 1.10.1 Release version.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/1.10.1.Release/pom.xml

The pom.xml has a dependency on         1.12.1.RELEASE and infact ***[QueryByExampleExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/query/QueryByExampleExecutor.html)*** javadocs suggest this class was added in 1.12 release.

The spring data commons version you've referenced is old 1.4.1.Release. So the fix for now would be to upgrade the spring data version to 1.12.1. The other fix could be to downgrade the spring-data-jpa to a version which uses spring data commons 1.4.1.Release version.

Btw you should look into using dependency management tool like Maven to avoid these kinds of problem in future.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using sbt for dependency management. The issue was that, after including a new library, I had to run the "activator eclipse" command. With this, activator will create me neat eclipse settings files and map all libraries and dependencies. I hadn't done this after adding some new dependencies in sbt. The result was that my project will compile perfectly in shell with activator but show issue in eclipse